# Disable Java ImageIO Chroma Subsampling

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio, jai, subsampling

I'm attempting to save a BufferedImage as JPEG using ImageIO. But even when saving using 100 quality, I am suffering quality loss due to Chroma SubSampling.

I have successfully fixed this issue by reverting to the older JAI libraries and explicitly setting the Horizontal and Vertical Subsampling to 1.
However a critical requirement is that I save the image as Progressive, which JAI doesn't seem to support.

Is there a way to disable sub-sampling using the newer ImageWriter?

Thanks in advance

If possible, I'd like to avoid ImageMagick

Comment: After extensive search on image writing/quality/compression issues. "Use ImageMagick" seems a common answer. Ideally I would like to know if this is possible in Java before going down the ImageMagick route.
I am not against 3rd party libraries so long as they are lightweight and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Maybe that information should be [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14149739/edit) into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reading of [JPEG Metadata Format Specification and Usage Notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html) seems to suggest that this is possible by writing the image with a custom `IIOMetadata`.

A search on the internet brings up https://codereview.appspot.com/3082041/patch/204004/210007, which seems to use ImageIO in exactly this manner.

I haven't tried it, and have no idea if it actually works.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have managed to get it working by using IIOMetadata, shocking performance compared to the old JAI, but it will do for now.

Comment: Tried and confirmed it works. 